# Во что лучше компилировать Java код, в .exe, или в .jar?

Tags: java, jar, exe

недавно начал изучать Java, и хочу узнать во что лучше компилировать Java код, в .exe, или в .jar, в чём их разница, и как это сделать(IDE - IntelliJ IDEA).

Comment: `.exe` - исполняемый файл для платформы Windows, '.jar' -- заархивированный файл, содержащий скомпилированный код в виде `.class` файлов а также опционально разного рода ресурсы (картинки, тексты для интернационализации, конфигурационные файлы и т.д.)  Для запуска программ на Java понадобится среда выполнения JRE.  Есть разные конвертеры `.jar`-файлов в `.exe`. Вопрос "что лучше" в данном случае объективного ответа не имеет, так как он зависит от ваших задач.

Answer (score 4):

Для начала давайте разберёмся, как всё устроено в `java`.
Начнём с запуска программ в среде разработки. Что происходит, когда вы запускаете простейшую программу (`Hello, world!`), нажимая кнопку `"run"`?

1. Сначала вы пишите код. Этот код записывается в файл с расширением `.java`;
2. Вы нажимаете кнопку `"run"`(запустить). А в это время происходят две вещи.

**Первая:** с помощью утилиты `javac` происходит процесс компиляции: код, понятный человеку, компилируется(переделывается) в код, понятный джаве(этот новый код называется байт-код и для человека он непонятен). Байт-код записывается в файл `.class`.

**Вторая:**
утилита `java` выполняет понятный ей байт-код из файла `.class`

А теперь главное: ответ на ваш вопрос.
Что же такое файл `.jar`?
"jar" переводится с английского как "банка", а вообще-то расшифровывается как *Java ARchive*. А представляет этот файл из себя  почти что `zip` - архив.

Только в этом файле содержатся две важные вещи: байт-коды ваших классов(файлы `.class`) и папка `META-INF`,в которой содержится специальный файл - `MANIFEST.MF`, в котором содержится информация для запуска программы.

Простейший `manifest`:

файл `MANIFEST.MF`:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Имя_вашего_класса_с_методом_main()
```

На самом деле `jar`-файл - это готовая программа для пользователя, которую можно запустить без среды разработки. Нужно лишь, чтобы на компьютере стояла `jre`. Запустить `jar` можно из командной строки. Если у вас приложение с графическим интерфейсом, то такой `jar` запускается двойным кликом.

Конечно, если программа, написанная вами, нужна лишь вам, паковать её в `jar` вовсе не обязательно: среда и без этого её запустит. Но если программа расчитанна на пользователя, то `jar` необходим.
Как упаковать вашу программу в `jar`, описано [например здесь](https://tehadm.ru/threads/kak-sozdat-ispolnjaemyj-jar-v-intellij-idea.667/).

**На счёт `exe`:** `exe` - расширение не `jav`'ы. Но обернуть `jar` в exe можно(например, с помощью программы `launch4j`), но это практически ничего не поменяет, поэтому я этого не рекомендую. Вместо `exe` используйте лучше `jar`.

Comment: `JAR => Java ARchive`

Comment: @ 
tym32167
это "удачное" совпадение =). И интересно, что совпадение "со смыслом": jar - в каком-то смысле и есть банка.

Comment: Не знаю про совпадения, акроним jar означает именно Java archive, если верить документации джавы на сайте оракла.

Comment: @ 
tym32167 Да, вы правы, jar - это Java archive ,но совпадение всё-таки удачное.

Comment: @Никита Пожалуйста, напишите в комментариях, что вас не устраивает в моём ответе или примите его как решение.

Comment: @Зонтик, это не совпадение, это намеренная отсылка к кофейной теме (Java, beans, jar ...)

Comment: @ tym32167 не знал, что и тут отсылка к кофейной теме.